# Latex Warning:Citation undefined

Tags: biblatex, citing

I was trapped by this citation for a long time. All my citations in bib suddendly didn't work and tex make told me there are not found in my bib.

My main tex file is as following:

```
\documentclass[GBK, colorlinks, notocbibind]{pkuthss}
\usepackage[backend = biber, style = caspervector, gbk]{biblatex}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{hologo}   

\newcommand{\myemph}[1]{\emph{\textcolor{red}{#1}}}   

\newcommand{\docversion}{v1.4 beta1}     

\addbibresource{pkuthss.bib}
\begin{document}
    \frontmatter

    \maketitle

    \include{chap/copyright}

    \include{chap/abstract}

    \tableofcontents

    \mainmatter

    \include{chap/introduction}

    \include{chap/chap1}
    \include{chap/chap2}
    \include{chap/chap3}

    \include{chap/conclusion}

    \appendix

    \printbibliography[heading = bibintoc]

    \backmatter

    \include{chap/acknowledge}

    \include{chap/originauth}
\end{document}
```

And my bib is here:

```
@online{biber,
    author = {Kime, Philip and Charette, Fran\c{c}ois},
    title = {Biber: A backend bibliography processor for biblatex (Version 0.9.9)},
    type = {M/OL},
    date = {2012-03-29},
    url = {http://biblatex-biber.sourceforge.net},
}

@online{biblatex,
    author = {Lehman, Philipp},
    title = {The biblatex Package: Programmable Bibliographies and Citations (Version 1.7)},
    type = {M/OL},
    date = {2011-11-13},
    url = {http://sourceforge.net/projects/biblatex/},
}

@online{biblatex-caspervector,
    author = {Vector, Casper Ti.},
    title = {biblatex 参考文献和引用样式：caspervector v0.1.3},
    type = {M/OL},
    date = {2012-05-31},
    url = {http://caspervector.googlecode.com/files/biblatex-caspervector-0.1.3.zip},
    userf = {zh},
}

@online{ctex,
    author = {{ctex.org}},
    title = {ctex 宏包说明（v1.02c）},
    type = {M/OL},
    date = {2011-03-11},
    url = {http://www.ctex.org/PackageCTeX/files.xml?action=download&file=ctex.pdf},
    userf = {zh},
}
```

What is wrong with my tex, could any one give me some advice?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Are you also compiling this using the sequence `(pdf)latex` -> `bibtex` -> `(pdf)latex` and perhaps one more `(pdf)latex`? You only need to do this when you change the `.bib` file. After that you can compile without the `bibtex` requirement.

Comment: This is not really a complete example: it needs the stuff before `\begin{document}`.  (And not all of it, only enough so the document can compile and show the problem you are having.)  Also: for what it is worth, appendices and and bibliographies are usually considered part of the 'back' or 'end' matter.

Comment: @Werner,thanks for your hint. Bibtex didn't work for me, and I use biber instead and it works.

Comment: @xiao啸 Your MWE does not show how you are trying to cite the references in your bib file. Since your problem seems to be with citations, your MWE should at least show how you are attempting to cite your references.